# Fusionpbx giving "Too many hops"issue

Tags: fusionpbx

I have set up multi tenant domain in FusionPBX trying to make two extentions talk with tls enabled. The registration and TLS part works perfect. But I am getting the following error when trying to call between them.. If I change the context to public I am able to make the calls but not able to access the dialplans like *870 etc. But if i change the context to my domain I am getting this error. Similarly if I provide my ip in Access Control domains my calls get diverted to public context. But if i dont I am not able to receive calls. Also from the logs I can see the max-forwards become 1 when calling between extentions which might be causing this issue. If calling a dialplan it returns to 70 and goes ahead. I tried giving it as a variable to 70 in internal profile but doesnt help. Please help me out as I am in an emergency to finish this. Please do let me know If any other information is required.

```
2018-06-22 11:59:19.795007 [NOTICE] switch_ivr.c:2201 Transfer sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl to XML[185@ortimo.voipmax.nl]
2018-06-22 11:59:19.795007 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:650 (sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl) State EXECUTE going to sleep
2018-06-22 11:59:19.795007 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:584 (sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl) Running State Change CS_ROUTING (Cur 1 Tot 10)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.795007 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:643 (sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl) State ROUTING
2018-06-22 11:59:19.795007 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:145 Call appears to be already acknowledged
2018-06-22 11:59:19.795007 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:154 sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl SOFIA ROUTING
2018-06-22 11:59:19.795007 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:236 sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Standard ROUTING
2018-06-22 11:59:19.795007 [INFO] mod_dialplan_xml.c:637 Processing 160 <160>->185 in context ortimo.voipmax.nl
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl parsing [ortimo.voipmax.nl->user_exists] continue=true
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (PASS) [user_exists] () =~ // break=on-false
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action set(user_exists=${user_exists id ${destination_number} ${domain_name}}) INLINE
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl set(user_exists=true)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.795007 [DEBUG] mod_dptools.c:1588 SET sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl [user_exists]=[true]
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (PASS) [user_exists] ${user_exists}(true) =~ /^true$/ break=on-false
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action set(extension_uuid=${user_data ${destination_number}@${domain_name} var extension_uuid}) INLINE
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl set(extension_uuid=10997a7f-fd74-4ae9-a174-733a968d96e2)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.795007 [DEBUG] mod_dptools.c:1588 SET sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl [extension_uuid]=[10997a7f-fd74-4ae9-a174-733a968d96e2]
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action set(hold_music=${user_data ${destination_number}@${domain_name} var hold_music}) INLINE
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl set(hold_music=)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.795007 [DEBUG] mod_dptools.c:1588 SET sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl [hold_music]=[UNDEF]
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action set(forward_all_enabled=${user_data ${destination_number}@${domain_name} var forward_all_enabled}) INLINE
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl set(forward_all_enabled=)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.815003 [DEBUG] mod_dptools.c:1588 SET sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl [forward_all_enabled]=[UNDEF]
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action set(forward_all_destination=${user_data ${destination_number}@${domain_name} var forward_all_destination}) INLINE
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl set(forward_all_destination=)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.815003 [DEBUG] mod_dptools.c:1588 SET sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl [forward_all_destination]=[UNDEF]
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action set(forward_busy_enabled=${user_data ${destination_number}@${domain_name} var forward_busy_enabled}) INLINE
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl set(forward_busy_enabled=)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.815003 [DEBUG] mod_dptools.c:1588 SET sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl [forward_busy_enabled]=[UNDEF]
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action set(forward_busy_destination=${user_data ${destination_number}@${domain_name} var forward_busy_destination}) INLINE
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl set(forward_busy_destination=)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.815003 [DEBUG] mod_dptools.c:1588 SET sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl [forward_busy_destination]=[UNDEF]
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action set(forward_no_answer_enabled=${user_data ${destination_number}@${domain_name} var forward_no_answer_enabled}) INLINE
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl set(forward_no_answer_enabled=)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.815003 [DEBUG] mod_dptools.c:1588 SET sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl [forward_no_answer_enabled]=[UNDEF]
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action set(forward_no_answer_destination=${user_data ${destination_number}@${domain_name} var forward_no_answer_destination}) INLINE
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl set(forward_no_answer_destination=)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.815003 [DEBUG] mod_dptools.c:1588 SET sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl [forward_no_answer_destination]=[UNDEF]
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action set(forward_user_not_registered_enabled=${user_data ${destination_number}@${domain_name} var forward_user_not_registered_enabled}) INLINE
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl set(forward_user_not_registered_enabled=)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.834991 [DEBUG] mod_dptools.c:1588 SET sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl [forward_user_not_registered_enabled]=[UNDEF]
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action set(forward_user_not_registered_destination=${user_data ${destination_number}@${domain_name} var forward_user_not_registered_destination}) INLINE
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl set(forward_user_not_registered_destination=)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.834991 [DEBUG] mod_dptools.c:1588 SET sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl [forward_user_not_registered_destination]=[UNDEF]
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action set(do_not_disturb=${user_data ${destination_number}@${domain_name} var do_not_disturb}) INLINE
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl set(do_not_disturb=)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.834991 [DEBUG] mod_dptools.c:1588 SET sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl [do_not_disturb]=[UNDEF]
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action set(call_timeout=${user_data ${destination_number}@${domain_name} var call_timeout}) INLINE
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl set(call_timeout=30)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.834991 [DEBUG] mod_dptools.c:1588 SET sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl [call_timeout]=[30]
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action set(missed_call_app=${user_data ${destination_number}@${domain_name} var missed_call_app}) INLINE
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl set(missed_call_app=)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.834991 [DEBUG] mod_dptools.c:1588 SET sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl [missed_call_app]=[UNDEF]
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action set(missed_call_data=${user_data ${destination_number}@${domain_name} var missed_call_data}) INLINE
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl set(missed_call_data=)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.834991 [DEBUG] mod_dptools.c:1588 SET sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl [missed_call_data]=[UNDEF]
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action set(toll_allow=${user_data ${destination_number}@${domain_name} var toll_allow}) INLINE
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl set(toll_allow=)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.854997 [DEBUG] mod_dptools.c:1588 SET sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl [toll_allow]=[UNDEF]
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action set(call_screen_enabled=${user_data ${destination_number}@${domain_name} var call_screen_enabled}) INLINE
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl set(call_screen_enabled=false)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.854997 [DEBUG] mod_dptools.c:1588 SET sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl [call_screen_enabled]=[false]
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl parsing [ortimo.voipmax.nl->caller-details] continue=true
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (FAIL) [caller-details] ${caller_destination}(185) =~ /^$/ break=never
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl parsing [ortimo.voipmax.nl->variables] continue=true
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (PASS) [variables] () =~ // break=on-false
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action export(origination_callee_id_name=${destination_number})
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action set(RFC2822_DATE=${strftime(%a, %d %b %Y %T %z)})
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl parsing [ortimo.voipmax.nl->call-direction] continue=true
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (PASS) [call-direction] ${call_direction}(local) =~ /^(inbound|outbound|local)$/ break=never
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl parsing [ortimo.voipmax.nl->user_record] continue=true
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (PASS) [user_record] () =~ // break=on-false
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action set(user_record=${user_data ${destination_number}@${domain_name} var user_record}) INLINE
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl set(user_record=)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.854997 [DEBUG] mod_dptools.c:1588 SET sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl [user_record]=[UNDEF]
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action set(from_user_exists=${user_exists id ${sip_from_user} ${sip_from_host}}) INLINE
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl set(from_user_exists=true)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.854997 [DEBUG] mod_dptools.c:1588 SET sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl [from_user_exists]=[true]
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (PASS) [user_record] ${user_exists}(true) =~ /^true$/ break=never
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (FAIL) [user_record] ${user_record}() =~ /^all$/ break=never
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (PASS) [user_record] ${user_exists}(true) =~ /^true$/ break=never
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (FAIL) [user_record] ${call_direction}(local) =~ /^inbound$/ break=never
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (FAIL) [user_record] ${user_record}() =~ /^inbound$/ break=never
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (PASS) [user_record] ${user_exists}(true) =~ /^true$/ break=never
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (FAIL) [user_record] ${call_direction}(local) =~ /^outbound$/ break=never
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (FAIL) [user_record] ${user_record}() =~ /^outbound$/ break=never
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (PASS) [user_record] ${user_exists}(true) =~ /^true$/ break=never
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (PASS) [user_record] ${call_direction}(local) =~ /^local$/ break=never
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (FAIL) [user_record] ${user_record}() =~ /^local$/ break=never
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (PASS) [user_record] ${from_user_exists}(true) =~ /^true$/ break=never
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action set(from_user_record=${user_data ${sip_from_user}@${sip_from_host} var user_record}) INLINE
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl set(from_user_record=)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.854997 [DEBUG] mod_dptools.c:1588 SET sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl [from_user_record]=[UNDEF]
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (PASS) [user_record] ${from_user_exists}(true) =~ /^true$/ break=never
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (FAIL) [user_record] ${from_user_record}() =~ /^all$/ break=never
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (PASS) [user_record] ${from_user_exists}(true) =~ /^true$/ break=never
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (FAIL) [user_record] ${call_direction}(local) =~ /^inbound$/ break=never
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (FAIL) [user_record] ${from_user_record}() =~ /^inbound$/ break=never
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (PASS) [user_record] ${from_user_exists}(true) =~ /^true$/ break=never
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (FAIL) [user_record] ${call_direction}(local) =~ /^outbound$/ break=never
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (FAIL) [user_record] ${from_user_record}() =~ /^outbound$/ break=never
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (PASS) [user_record] ${from_user_exists}(true) =~ /^true$/ break=never
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (PASS) [user_record] ${call_direction}(local) =~ /^local$/ break=never
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (FAIL) [user_record] ${from_user_record}() =~ /^local$/ break=never
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (FAIL) [user_record] ${record_session}() =~ /^true$/ break=on-false
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl parsing [ortimo.voipmax.nl->redial] continue=true
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (FAIL) [redial] destination_number(185) =~ /^(redial|\*870)$/ break=on-true
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (PASS) [redial] () =~ // break=never
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action hash(insert/${domain_name}-last_dial/${caller_id_number}/${destination_number})
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl parsing [ortimo.voipmax.nl->speed_dial] continue=false
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (FAIL) [speed_dial] destination_number(185) =~ /^\*0(.*)$/ break=on-false
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl parsing [ortimo.voipmax.nl->default_caller_id] continue=true
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (PASS) [default_caller_id] ${emergency_caller_id_number}() =~ /^$/ break=never
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action set(emergency_caller_id_name=${default_emergency_caller_id_name}) INLINE
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl set(emergency_caller_id_name=)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.854997 [DEBUG] mod_dptools.c:1588 SET sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl [emergency_caller_id_name]=[UNDEF]
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action set(emergency_caller_id_number=${default_emergency_caller_id_number}) INLINE
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl set(emergency_caller_id_number=)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.854997 [DEBUG] mod_dptools.c:1588 SET sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl [emergency_caller_id_number]=[UNDEF]
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (FAIL) [default_caller_id] ${outbound_caller_id_number}(160) =~ /^$/ break=never
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl parsing [ortimo.voipmax.nl->185] continue=false
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Regex (PASS) [185] destination_number(185) =~ /^(185)$/ break=on-false
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action set(hangup_after_bridge=true)
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action set(continue_on_fail=true)
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action set(accountcode=ortimo.voipmax.nl)
Dialplan: sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Action transfer(185 XML ortimo.voipmax.nl)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.854997 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:286 (sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl) State Change CS_ROUTING -> CS_EXECUTE
2018-06-22 11:59:19.854997 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:643 (sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl) State ROUTING going to sleep
2018-06-22 11:59:19.854997 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:584 (sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl) Running State Change CS_EXECUTE (Cur 1 Tot 10)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.854997 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:650 (sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl) State EXECUTE
2018-06-22 11:59:19.854997 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:209 sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl SOFIA EXECUTE
2018-06-22 11:59:19.854997 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:328 sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Standard EXECUTE
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl export(origination_callee_id_name=185)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.854997 [DEBUG] switch_channel.c:1296 EXPORT (export_vars) [origination_callee_id_name]=[185]
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl set(RFC2822_DATE=Fri, 22 Jun 2018 11:59:19 +0200)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.854997 [DEBUG] mod_dptools.c:1588 SET sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl [RFC2822_DATE]=[Fri, 22 Jun 2018 11:59:19 +0200]
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl hash(insert/ortimo.voipmax.nl-last_dial/160/185)
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl set(hangup_after_bridge=true)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.854997 [DEBUG] mod_dptools.c:1588 SET sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl [hangup_after_bridge]=[true]
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl set(continue_on_fail=true)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.874992 [DEBUG] mod_dptools.c:1588 SET sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl [continue_on_fail]=[true]
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl set(accountcode=ortimo.voipmax.nl)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.874992 [DEBUG] mod_dptools.c:1588 SET sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl [accountcode]=[ortimo.voipmax.nl]
EXECUTE sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl transfer(185 XML ortimo.voipmax.nl)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.874992 [NOTICE] switch_ivr.c:2094 Hangup sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl [CS_EXECUTE] [EXCHANGE_ROUTING_ERROR]
2018-06-22 11:59:19.874992 [DEBUG] switch_core_session.c:2885 sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl skip receive message [PHONE_EVENT] (channel is hungup already)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.874992 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:650 (sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl) State EXECUTE going to sleep
2018-06-22 11:59:19.874992 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:584 (sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl) Running State Change CS_HANGUP (Cur 1 Tot 10)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.874992 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:850 (sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl) Callstate Change RINGING -> HANGUP
2018-06-22 11:59:19.874992 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:852 (sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl) State HANGUP
2018-06-22 11:59:19.874992 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:449 Channel sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl hanging up, cause: EXCHANGE_ROUTING_ERROR
2018-06-22 11:59:19.874992 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:588 Responding to INVITE with: 483
2018-06-22 11:59:19.874992 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:60 sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl Standard HANGUP, cause: EXCHANGE_ROUTING_ERROR
2018-06-22 11:59:19.874992 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:852 (sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl) State HANGUP going to sleep
2018-06-22 11:59:19.874992 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:619 (sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl) State Change CS_HANGUP -> CS_REPORTING
2018-06-22 11:59:19.874992 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:584 (sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl) Running State Change CS_REPORTING (Cur 1 Tot 10)
2018-06-22 11:59:19.874992 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:938 (sofia/internal/160@ortimo.voipmax.nl) State REPORTING
send 822 bytes to tls/[217.100.229.30]:1328 at 11:59:19.908264:
------------------------------------------------------------------------
SIP/2.0 483 Too Many Hops
Via: SIP/2.0/TLS 10.30.21.135:1523;rport=1328;branch=z9hG4bK1486366143;received=217.100.229.30
Max-Forwards: 1
From: "160" <sip:160@ortimo.voipmax.nl>;tag=226805503
To: <sip:185@ortimo.voipmax.nl>;tag=r1m3rNrQHc5ar
Call-ID: 936082658@10.30.21.135
CSeq: 2 INVITE
User-Agent: FreeSWITCH
Accept: application/sdp
Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE
Supported: timer, path, replaces
Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, presence, as-feature-event, dialog, line-seize, call-info, sla, include-session-description, presence.winfo, message-summary, refer
Reason: Q.850;cause=25;text="EXCHANGE_ROUTING_ERROR"
Content-Length: 0
Remote-Party-ID: "185" <sip:185@ortimo.voipmax.nl>;party=calling;privacy=off;screen=no

------------------------------------------------------------------------
recv 284 bytes from tls/[217.100.229.30]:1328 at 11:59:20.017886:
------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACK sip:185@ortimo.voipmax.nl:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/TLS 10.30.21.135:1523;rport;branch=z9hG4bK1486366143
From: "160" <sip:160@ortimo.voipmax.nl>;tag=226805503
To: <sip:185@ortimo.voipmax.nl>;tag=r1m3rNrQHc5ar
Call-ID: 936082658@10.30.21.135
CSeq: 2 ACK
Content-Length: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by providing the max-forwards to 70 as a condition in the inbound routes. Please follow this solution if anyone stumbles upon an error like mine. 
Destinations->Inbound Routes->Extention

Tag : Condition
Type: max-forwards
Data: 70

Leave others default and Save. This should hopefully rectify the problem. Cheers!